# Google Analytics 4 - Get URLs of visited pages

Tags: google-analytics

After the update of 'Google Analytics' to 'Google Analytics 4' I can't find out - how to get list of URLs of visited pages by users. How to check it?

I found some tutorials but it needs to generate tag manager but I don't want to do it for each section with links.

There is no out of the box option like before?

Comment: I'm just going to be creating GA4 + Universal properties I think, asked if there's any way to just add UA to GA4 property: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154503/how-to-enable-universal-analytics-on-existing-google-analytics-4-property